# Microsoft django logout

Tags: django

I want to perform Microsoft logout from my Django application, I have logged IN my user and now  I am sending few parameters

```py
{
  'tenant':'ec0a1000-3407-4d2f-81f9-dfd1179718dc',
  'client_id' : 'f03b5c74-f63f-4bbd-a920-70c91b201c97',
  'code' : code,
  'client_secret' : '2hv8Q~oHdAeVS-DdmaJA6vZAaH8PzM.Inoeddb_P',
  'redirect_uri' : 'http://localhost:8000/callback', 
  'scope' : 'user.read',
  'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
}
```

but I got this error so can you please tell me the solution of this error.

[image]

Comment: 1. Here is clearly saying that you have to provide `name` key, but here is no `name` in your request, 2. Looks like that you trying to login again instead of logout, 3. Why do you trying to send request to Microsoft on logout? It seems like OAuth standard, afaik you don't need to logout at remote server, just close Django session without sending external requests

Comment: I hope the credentials (Client ID, client secret, etc.) you have specified in your question are placeholders and not the actual credentials? If they are the actual credentials please make update them ASAP as you have exposed them. Meanwhile you can raise a mod flag to get your question redacted and remove these credentials.